# retrofit response is true but no data fetch in serverDB

Tags: android, rest, api, android-studio, retrofit2

I have problem in parsing data thru my API. my retrofit code was sending true state on my response but if i look for my ServerDb, the response not come.

API:

```
         @POST("/api/Database/NewLocation")
                Call<MapDetails> mapDetailLocation(@Body MapDetails 
mapDetails);
```

Map Details:

```
    public class MapDetails {

    private String serialNumber;
    private String coordinate1;
    private String coordinate2;
    private String dateTime;
    private String speed;
    private Integer Port;

    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }

       public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
           this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
       }

       public String getCoordinate1() {
           return coordinate1;
       }

       public void setCoordinate1(String coordinate1) {
           this.coordinate1 = coordinate1;
       }

       public String getCoordinate2() {
           return coordinate2;
       }

       public void setCoordinate2(String coordinate2) {
           this.coordinate2 = coordinate2;
       }

       public String getDateTime() {
           return dateTime;
       }

       public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
           this.dateTime = dateTime;
       }

       public String getSpeed() {
           return speed;
       }

       public void setSpeed(String speed) {
           this.speed = speed;
       }

       public Integer getPort() {
           return Port;
       }

       public void setPort(Integer port) {
           Port = port;
       }

       public MapDetails(String serialNumber, String coordinate1, String                      
           coordinate2, String dateTime, String speed, Integer port) {
           this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
           this.coordinate1 = coordinate1;
           this.coordinate2 = coordinate2;
           this.dateTime = dateTime;
           this.speed = speed;
           Port = port;


       }
   }
```

RetrofitClient:

```
          public class RetrofitClient {
       private static  final  String BASE_URL="http://58.69.149.164:9114";
       private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
       private Retrofit retrofit;

       private RetrofitClient() {
           retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
       }
       public static  synchronized  RetrofitClient getmInstance(){
           if(mInstance==null){
               mInstance=new RetrofitClient();
           }
           return mInstance;
       }
       public Api getApi(){
           return  retrofit.create(Api.class);
       }

    activity:

         MapDetails mapDetails = new MapDetails(gg, lat, lon,        
           `enter code here`currentDateTimeString, "0", 9090);
                    setLocation(mapDetails);


                    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new        
                DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    SQLiteDatabase db = 
               databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    boolean accepted = 
                 databaseHelper.saveLocationToLocalDatabase(lat, lon, 
             currentDateTimeString, syncPassed, db);
                    if (accepted == true)
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Location Found", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    else
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Error Location", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();

                }

                private void setLocation(MapDetails mapDetails) {

                    initializeRetrofit(mapDetails);
                }

                private void initializeRetrofit(MapDetails mapDetails) {
                    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl("http://58.69.149.164:9114")

             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

                    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

                    Api locate = retrofit.create(Api.class);

                    SetMapLocationApiCaller(locate, mapDetails);


                }

                private void SetMapLocationApiCaller(Api locate, MapDetails 
            mapDetails) {

                    Call<MapDetails> call = 
               locate.mapDetailLocation(mapDetails);
                    executeCallAsynchronously(call);
                }

                private void executeCallAsynchronously(Call call) {
                    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) 
                     {
                            Toast.makeText(NavDrawerFleet.this, ""+response, 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                            Toast.makeText(NavDrawerFleet.this, 
               t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
```

The response here is true means the transaction is true.. but in my server db, no data fetched.....

also my api is this:

[image]

```
    if I send that, i will having a response from my serverDb...
```

Comment: A suggestion: Don't expose your API URL.

Comment: on response, you never saved your data to your db, all you're doing is showing a Toast.

Comment: its ok sir, its only local

Answer (score 0):

```
     @POST("api/Database/NewLocation")
     Call<ServerResponse> mapDetailLocation(@Body MapDetails mapDetails);
```

**Add this class in your code to get Response from server.**

**ServerResponse.java class**

```
public class ServerResponse {

@SerializedName("Status")
@Expose
private Integer status;
@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String message;

public Integer getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

}
```

**Change this**

```
private static  final  String BASE_URL="http://58.69.149.164:9114/";
```

**in `initializeRetrofit` too**

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://58.69.149.164:9114/")
```

And this

```
 Call<MapDetails> call = 
               locate.mapDetailLocation(mapDetails);
                    executeCallAsynchronously(call);
                }
```

TO

```
 Call<ServerResponse> call = 
           locate.mapDetailLocation(mapDetails);
                executeCallAsynchronously(call);
            }
```

**Chnage your `executeCallAsynchronously` as**

```
private void executeCallAsynchronously(Call call) {
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)
        {
            ServerResponse res = response.body();
            int status = res.getStatus();
            String msg = res.getMessage();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(NavDrawerFleet.this,
                    t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: upon the impplementation sir, is my code sending post to api.. is correct?

Comment: updated code according to your code, Try it. if you have any confusion let me know.

Comment: the error on status is "Cannot Deserailize the current JSON objecy (e.g{"name":"value"}) into type System.Collections.Generic.List...........     

//                                              

on the msg : To fix this errir either change the JSON to JSON array(e.g.[1,2,3]) or change the deserialize type so that it is a normal......

Comment: your response is `JSON Array`. it should be `JSON Object`. Kindly change response on Server. it will solve your problem.

Comment: is it possible that retrofit can send to server as json object rather than json array?

Comment: didn't get you at `retrofit can send to server as json object rather than json array`